# 404 error while accessing SP Server Site 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, iis, web-config, server

404 error while accessing SP Server Site 2013.

This is an intermittent issue.

We recently had a crypto attack on all servers hence everything was turned off.

When everything was settled, we started the server, application pools, did IIS reset,reboot of server.

however all users are still facing issues while accessing all the sharepoint sites.

They are receiving:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Can someone advise on this?

thank you

Comment: could you access "/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx" of your sites? you can check ULS log to find more information about this issue. A similar blog for your reference: https://www.gtconsult.com/fix-sharepoint-404-file-not-found-error/

Comment: Try to run PSconfig on all your SP servers if it finish well. You can try this with PS powershell:(it will reinstall IIS sites and everything) PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install